# How to attached pdf to email

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am doing a app for Ipad,I am trying to attached a pdf file to send by email ,for this I create a pdf like this.

```
pageSize= CGSizeMake(612, 792);
    NSString *fileName=@"prueba.pdf";
    NSArray *paths= NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *pdfFileName= [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

    NSString *url=[fileName stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
    [self generatePdfWithFilePath:pdfFileName];
    NSData *pdfData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:url];
```

the next step is create a email to send the pdf I dis this, like this..

```
   if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]){
        MFMailComposeViewController *mailer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        mailer.mailComposeDelegate = self;
        [mailer setSubject:@"esto es para probar"];
        NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:currentuser.email, nil];
        [mailer setToRecipients:toRecipients];
        [mailer addAttachmentData:pdfData mimeType:@"application/pdf" fileName:fileName];
        NSString *emailBody = @"correo prueba";
        [mailer setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];
        [self presentModalViewController:mailer animated:YES];
        mailer.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPageSheet;

    }else{
...
```

I generate I create the pdf and everything is right, when I see the email I see de pdf attached like a image (picture), but the problem is that when I receive the email nothing is attached.

any idea

Comment: can you print in log your `fileName`? it should be `xyz.pdf`.

Comment: i mean.. did he get the mail which was sent from phone...?

Comment: @mvp OK, well he actually says he receives the email as noted here - "but the problem is that when I receive the email nothing is attached." The issue is as nothing is attached.

Answer (score 3):

It seems to me that in your code you are reversing the order of the two following steps:

```
NSData *pdfData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:url];
[self generatePdfWithFilePath:pdfFileName];
```

If I interpret correctly the meaning of `generatePdfWithFilePath:pdfFileName`, I assume this step should be executed before the other. I.e.:

```
[self generatePdfWithFilePath:pdfFileName];
NSData *pdfData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:url];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That seems more like an answer now. +1

Comment: @Popeye: thanks for your comment. It was not a comment indeed, but an attempt to offer an explanation. I reworded it.

Comment: Thanks @sergio for you comment, I change the order, but still don't work. any other idea

Answer (score 0):

Finally work, I put the solution for someone.. thanks

```
 pageSize= CGSizeMake(612, 792);
    NSString *fileName=@"prueba.pdf";
    NSArray *paths= NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *pdfFileName= [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
    [self generatePdfWithFilePath:pdfFileName];
    NSData *pdfData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:pdfFileName];
    G7DatabaseInterface *databaseInterface = [[DatabaseInterface alloc] init];
    G7User *currentuser=[databaseInterface userByUsername:self.appDelegate.userName];
```

ok I explain better, sorry, before to fix it up I have this, the problem was in this line

```
NSString *url=[fileName stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
```

my url was prueba.pdf/prueba.pdf so the path was wrong!!

I fix it up like this

```
NSString *pdfFileName= [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
```

and erase the *url I don't use it.

Comment: I agree with `sergio` this is why I have put a downvote. If some sort of explanation is given to what the actual solution is I will remove.

Comment: As said I have removed the -1. If this worked for you, you may want to accept it.